# PHP Socket identification through multiple requests

Tags: php, sockets, session, udp, client

I'm making a PHP api which creates a client socket connection with my Java SocketServer. This is going to be used for a chat application for learning purpose.

So I'm setting up the whole api at the moment and I'm kinda wondering how I should identify my socket. To store the socket I'm planning to store it in $_SESSION. I have read that the socket id is not a good way to identify it.

What's the best way to store a socket in a session and can I have some code examples?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey @Timon, unless there's some information missing here, you will not be able to store a socket in $_SESSION - a socket is a resource like a file handle. Since different requests may be handled by different worker processes (which cannot share handles), you cannot store these resources for use later on. If you need to persist identities between requests, forwarding PHP session IDs to your Java  server may be a better way to do it, so that you can resume a session state even when the sockets are not the same

Comment: @Timon why not u bind some salt(unique ID) to your socket id and then using some encryption technique on it. this will save your socket id and you identify it easily.hope its works for you

Comment: You will be unable, if not very difficult (to implement), to share sessions between different programming platforms. I suggest you use a Messaging Queue system, such as [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) to do the push and pull of messages. Incidentally, [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273500/rachet-chat-application-connection-closed-immediately-after-established-when-t) has all it takes to create a new PHP chat application with laravel out of the box

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way:
1) make a stand alone php  which is creates a socket client and then starts an infitive loop:
2) in every loop it checks the chat_table with a token_id indicates that the chat session
3) If there is a new message from users your php post it them via socket connection
4) usleep(200000); //

So if its acceptable your main php will initiate these stand alone php via exec() like:

```
exec('php -f client.php '.escapeshellarg($sessionId).' > /dev/null &');
```

with these argumants "&" this process will be handled in background your main php will NOT wait that row.
At your client.php you can the $sessionId with :

```
$sessionId = $_SERVER['argv'][1];
```

After an pre-defined expire time your infitive looped client.php can stop itself. there is no activity in the table for that session it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "store" a socket in between requests, it just doesn't work that way.

What you can do, is to send the session ID (or some other similar token) via that socket, so that the receiving end (your Java app) can identify different clients via session IDs.